# How to add multiple generic type arguments to xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics

I have this Base Class for my Xaml pages, which defines like this:
`

```
public abstract class BasePageView<T, VM> : Page where T : class, IBaseClass, new() where VM : BaseMainViewModel<T>,new()
```

I want to use it as a reference to my new pages, and I want to fill the argument types, which I'm using like this:
`

```
<Commons:BasePageView x:TypeArguments="Db:Project, Commons:BaseMainViewModel" x:Class="Facade_User.Pages.Page_ProjectConfig"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Facade_User.Pages"
  xmlns:Db="clr-namespace:Facade_DB;assembly=Facade_DB"
  xmlns:Commons="clr-namespace:WpfCommons;assembly=WpfCommons"
```

The error im seeing is:

```
Error XDG0062
GenericArguments[1], 'System.Object', on 'WpfCommons.BasePageView2[T,VM]' violates
 the constraint of type 'VM'.Facade_User
Page_ProjectConfig.xaml 1
```

I really could use the help.

Comment: Facade_User has to have a parameterless constructor and derive from BaseViewModel. Can you show us the code for relevant classes please?

Comment: It has parameter-less constructor and it does derive from BaseViewModel. As I explained in my own answer, my mistake was calling the BaseViewModel in Xaml instead of "ProjectViewModel" (which is the sub and real class)

Comment: And if you look at the date and time of my comment you will notice it was made a minute before your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, and it was my careless mistake. I called for the Base ViewModel, e.g. `Commons: BaseMainViewModel` when I wanted to call the ViewModel, instead of calling the real ViewModel. I Fixed the issue:

```
<Commons:BasePageView x:TypeArguments="local:ProjectViewModel, Db:Project"
```